# git username visible to nginx

Tags: git, nginx

I have gitlab server running behind nginx. Need to do some custom authentication whenever client is executing any of the git commands (git clone, git pull, git commit, etc.,).

How nginx get read the git username?

Comment: Does git use http transport? What kind of custom authentication do you mean?

Comment: I am not sure about http transport protocol. I have a git project configured as public. However some of the users should not access that project.

Answer (score 1):

NGiNX means [HTTPS access for GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html).

If so, GitLab itself will, through NGiNX, request your username/password (unless you have a `git config credential.helper` in place, which would have cached those credentials)

This has nothing to do with `user.name`/`user.email` (only used for commit authorship).

Comment: I am not looking for username / password authentication. I would like to some custom validation / permission scheme using username and git url. For that I need read the values of username and git URL. git URL I am able to access, but not sure how to access username.

Comment: @SVGKRaju There is no dedicated username (when using HTTPS): you can test / validate through `git ls-remote https://<aUser>:<aPassword>@yourServer/<anAccount>/<aRepo>`. But you need to know what user access you want to validate

Answer (score -1):

If no username/email is set git use the default values which is the default machine name and logged in user

```
$
$ git init tmp
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/tmp/.git/
$ cd tmp
$ git commit -m"Message" --allow-empty

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@....(none)')
```

Comment: I am aware of git config. My question is how nginx know who is trying to access a git repo.